# React Native: useState not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been messing around with trying to make a Leage Of Legends stats app using the Riot Games API, I have recently run into an issue... When I run the "handlePress" function it gets everything from "fetchId1" correctly but when it gets to "fetchId2" it logs the "summonerId" retrived from "fetchId1" as null, how would I go about fixing this?

Thanks, Lachie.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Button, Text, Image, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

export default function getSummonerInfo(props) {
  const [url1, setUrl1] = useState(
    "https://oc1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"
  );
  const [url2, setUrl2] = useState(
    "https://oc1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/"
  );
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [apikey, setApikey] = useState(props.api);
  const [tempPlayer, setTempPlayer] = useState("");
  const [profileIcon, setProfileIcon] = useState(29);
  const [summonerLevel, setSummonerLevel] = useState(null);
  const [summonerId, setSummonerId] = useState(null);
  const [accountId, setAccountId] = useState(null);
  const [accountPuuid, setAccountPuuid] = useState(null);

  let Url1 = url1 + tempPlayer + "?api_key=" + apikey;
  let Url2 = url2 + summonerId + "?api_key=" + apikey;

  const fetchId1 = () => {
    fetch(Url1)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setName(responseJson.name);
        setSummonerLevel(responseJson.summonerLevel);
        setSummonerId(responseJson.summonerId);
        setAccountId(responseJson.accountId);
        setAccountPuuid(responseJson.accountPuuid);
        setProfileIcon(responseJson.profileIconId);
        console.log(responseJson);
        fetchId2();
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setName("Player Not Found!");
        setSummonerLevel("N/A");
        setAccountId("N/A");
      });
  };
  const fetchId2 = () => {
    fetch(Url2)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson2) => {
        console.log(responseJson2);
        return responseJson2;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(summonerId);
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  let profileIconUrl = `https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/11.16.1/img/profileicon/${profileIcon}.png`;

  function handlePress() {
    fetchId1();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Summoner name"
        value={tempPlayer}
        onChangeText={(text) => setTempPlayer(text)}
      />
      <Button
        color="#8364B7"
        onPress={() => handlePress()}
        title={`Search Stats For "${tempPlayer}"`}
      />
      {name != null && (
        <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.profileIcon}
            source={{
              uri: profileIconUrl,
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.summonerName}>Summoner Name:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subSummonerName}>
            {name} (LVL {summonerLevel})
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.summonerId}>ID: {accountId}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  searchContainer: {
    margin: 10,
  },
  label: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    margin: 10,
  },
  profileContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 24,
    borderRadius: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#161327",
  },
  profileIcon: {
    marginTop: 32,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: "#8364B7",
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderRadius: 150,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
  summonerName: {
    marginTop: 16,
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#fff",
  },
  subSummonerName: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#B6B6B6",
  },
  summonerId: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#B6B6B6",
  },
});
```

Comment: are you only calling fetchId2 and doing nothing with it

Comment: Right now I'm just calling it to get the responce in console to get it working @BlackHole

Answer (score 0):

Your ‘fetch Url2’ call should be in its own ‘useEffect’ and have a dependency on ‘summnerId’. Have a guard against summnerId being null for the ip call.

Also recommend wrapping these functions in a sync/await.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state in React is an asynchronous action, much like your "fetch" action.
So what essentially happens is that when you call `fetch2()` in `fetch1()`,
you have no guarantee that `setSummonerId(...)` actually finished.

What you can do instead of calling `fetch2()` from `fetch1()`, is utilizing React's `useEffect` hook which runs it's callback function whenever there is a change in at-least one of it's dependencies.

You're looking for something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (summonerId === null) {
      return;
   }
   fetch2();
}, [summonerId])
```

This means that every time `summonerId` changes, it runs the callback again,
checks if the value is not null, i.e. `setSummonerId(...)` has finished.
And then call fetch2.

P.S. would recommend replacing all of those seperate states that get updated in `fetch1()` into 1 state object so that it would re-render only once instead of 6 times.
Thus improving your app's performance.

Comment: you don't have to add fetch2 inside the dependency array